# jQuery form leave disabled after a page refresh

Tags: jquery, forms, refresh

I have a form with some selection input field, if the selector is equal to something it disable some other input fields. This working good.

But when the form refresh (with the pre-loaded input), for example in the case the form is not valid, the others fields are not disabled.

My code:

```
  $('#some_selector_id').change(function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (val == "something")
            {
                  $('#other_field').prop('disabled', true);
            } else {
                  $('#other_field').prop('disabled', false);
            }
      });
```

To maintain the code dry, I don't want to repeat code, there is a method to follow like: if `.change` or `.val_is` do `this`?

Comment: add .change() to trigger your change event on page load

Comment: You can chain the change methods. `$('#some_selector_id').change(function() { //... }).change()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the dom ready event, after you have bound the change event, you should just trigger the event manually:

```
$('#some_selector_id').change();
```

That will cause the change handler to run.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$('#some_selector_id').change();
```

in document.ready